# How can one distinguish the host and the port in an IPv6 URL?

Tags: ipv6, url

URLs always have this format:

```
<protocol>://<host>[:<port>]/[<path>][#<hash>]
```

The problem is that IPv6 uses colons, just like the separator of port and host, e.g:

```
2001:db8:1f70::999:de8:7648:6e8
```

But what if this is the host, and I want to connect to it with HTTP on port 100?

```
http://2001:db8:1f70::999:de8:7648:6e8:100/
```

The problem is the last colon. Since zero's are omitted with double colons (between 1f70 and 999), it's unknown if ':100' belongs to the IP or the port number. How can we know this?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The notation in that case is to encode the IPv6 IP number in square brackets:

```
http://[2001:db8:1f70::999:de8:7648:6e8]:100/
```

That's [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), section 3.2.2: Host

> A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6
>       [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal
>       within square brackets ("[" and "]").  This is the only place where
>       square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax.  In
>       anticipation of future, as-yet-undefined IP literal address formats,
>       an implementation may use an optional version flag to indicate such a
>       format explicitly rather than rely on heuristic determination.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the brackets are *not* optional. It's the only unambiguous mechanism by which the browser can identify a numeric IPv6 address.

Comment: Shouldn't the port be inside the brackets?

Comment: @jayarjo No, as the brackets are there to provide disambiguation between the IP address, which contains colons, and the port, which is separated from the IP address by a colon.